# Num Lock function has changed after upgrading to UBUNTU 13.10

Tags: 13.10, numlock, functions

I faced a strange function 
I installed ubuntu 13.10 and all the time the number pad on the right of my keyboard is typing number without pressing Num Lock and when I turn it on It does the job when Num Lock is normally off .

does anyone have this problem ? and any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: can turn it on on boot and you can close it manually?

Comment: by default Num lock led is off but keypad is typing numbers but when I turn it on it does the other function

Comment: if you want, we can turn it on with led at boot , sync led and keys.

Comment: yes I want to how ?

Comment: i added it as answer.

Comment: This isn't  a duplicate, it's for 13.10 (instead of 12.04) and the answers are different (/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf instead of /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install this application :

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Edit this file :

```
sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

Add Line at the end of file :

> greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on

Comment: Thank you! I actually had the opposite issue and modified the command to turn off my numlock, since it was always getting in the way :)! (simply used off instead of on :))

Answer (score 0):

Enabling numpad at boot will care of problem. With this link you can sync light and keys.

[How to enable numpad at boot](http://ubuntuguide.net/enable-number-pad-numlock-at-startup-in-ubuntu-login-window)

Comment: there is nothing in this file : /etc/gdm/Init/Default   that I add anything to it or edit it.

Comment: there is another options too. try others.